# Which serializer is better for pyspark : MarshalSerializer or PickleSerializer?

Tags: pyspark, serialization

I am using pyspark and want to increase network performance and memory tuning.Can anyone suggest which Serializer is better for pyspark: **MarshalSerializer** or **PickleSerializer**.